# python: sheet.row_values working unexpectedly in loop

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to read an excel file using xlrd in python and converting it into nested dictionary. The method seems to work as expected when I run on single section of excel sheet but it reads data unexpectedly when I run the code in loop over more than one iteration. Below I have attached the code, the result and file I am using for importing.

The code is:

```
import xlrd

row = []
family_data = []
row_index = [10]
row_end = [14]
#row_index = [7,13,26,51,71,83,112,134,158,174]
#row_end = [9,22,47, 67, 79, 107, 129, 153, 169, 195]


#i,j= 0,0

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(r"D:\Downloads\temp.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

for j,e in zip(row_index,row_end):
    print(j , e)
    col_a = sheet.col_values(2, j, e)
    for xx in range(e-j):
        row.append(sheet.row_values(xx+j, 3, 15))
        print(xx+j)
    
    my_dict = {a : b for a, b in zip(col_a, row)}
    
    print(my_dict)
    #family_data.append({str(sheet.cell(j-1,2))[6:-1]: my_dict})
    my_dict = {}
```

The result that I get is as expected:

> 10 14
> 10
> 11
> 12
> 13
> {'L4': [0.3609293873262742, 8.52965299131549,
> 0.197455982671757, 14.665172843007683, 2.425241061340595, 2.8897891887570437, 5.181364206838781, 3.693061340418844, 4.100211816213466, 9.543049279229649, 9.72216452352149, 6.024503044135052], 'L5': [9.298920548279625, 3.492024424046254, 5.233947529069509, 16.87844516822769, 9.167887432485388, 9.77717029370055, 2.207390435381904, 18.795951949648412, 4.739064601349008, 8.992069699166903, 5.028492087969589, 18.485851177736595], 'L6': [8.238941623230998, 19.88437022106018, 5.6488779908881925, 13.019967132088638, 13.078365245612124, 19.704402577213354, 13.526881824904706, 9.590796715002218, 9.106093791540491, 8.525062610097079, 5.03400203021876, 18.321200188716787], 'L7': [15.91895476157644, 8.445241722677046, 7.309852625838729, 16.725425760108124, 13.567929159133552, 11.753110673581128, 9.775172820161108, 18.937806878222403, 14.276145575085344, 8.761762879263777, 16.289251830188714, 5.344111776463418]}

but when I modify 5th and 6th lines of code as:

```
row_index = [2, 10]
row_end = [5, 14]
```

the output is as:

> 2 5
> 2
> 3
> 4 {'l1': [13.034244487619757, 8.983231349575933,
> 2.4352126031212373, 16.93691226179657, 5.443827901209584, 13.893052688957258, 1.6502338610319134, 5.932773879221198, 1.455047372604208, 6.47717511524919, 11.442291754513645, 8.9142810885123], 'L2': [15.611306849072477, 1.4764854675018624, 0.7244507149941226, 4.465833248792674, 5.414076145140241, 18.23705271798222, 18.069897034790753, 1.9746179109460704, 15.876985204886543, 3.8450748817047, 16.008005622091154, 13.890598557483093], 'L3': [15.118347538470918, 1.9413280241085151, 15.758578243390017, 10.51568840954127, 19.6064413088176, 12.624793088371852, 2.711171326768813, 16.662465726145182, 18.925802016128944, 6.807976597195189, 11.13022437494946, 17.977080331943075]}
> 10 14
> 10
> 11
> 12
> 13
> **{'L4': [13.034244487619757, 8.983231349575933, 2.4352126031212373, 16.93691226179657, 5.443827901209584, 13.893052688957258, 1.6502338610319134, 5.932773879221198, 1.455047372604208, 6.47717511524919, 11.442291754513645, 8.9142810885123], 'L5': [15.611306849072477, 1.4764854675018624, 0.7244507149941226, 4.465833248792674, 5.414076145140241, 18.23705271798222, 18.069897034790753, 1.9746179109460704, 15.876985204886543, 3.8450748817047, 16.008005622091154, 13.890598557483093], 'L6': [15.118347538470918, 1.9413280241085151, 15.758578243390017, 10.51568840954127, 19.6064413088176, 12.624793088371852, 2.711171326768813, 16.662465726145182, 18.925802016128944, 6.807976597195189, 11.13022437494946, 17.977080331943075], 'L7': [0.3609293873262742, 8.52965299131549, 0.197455982671757, 14.665172843007683, 2.425241061340595, 2.8897891887570437, 5.181364206838781, 3.693061340418844, 4.100211816213466, 9.543049279229649, 9.72216452352149, 6.024503044135052]}**

The sheet that I am using is shown here in image form and pasted, (I don't see an option to attach the file)

[image: Excel data]

> Heading 1
> l1  13.03424    8.983231    2.435213    16.93691    5.443828    13.89305    1.650234    5.932774    1.455047    6.477175    11.44229    8.914281
> L2  15.6113068  1.476485    0.724451    4.465833    5.414076    18.23705    18.0699 1.974618    15.87699    3.845075    16.00801    13.8906     L3  15.1183475  1.941328    15.75858    10.51569    19.60644    12.62479    2.711171    16.66247    18.9258 6.807977    11.13022    17.97708
>
> ```
>                                                   Heading 2                                               L4  0.36092939  8.529653    0.197456    14.66517    2.425241    2.889789    5.181364    3.693061    4.100212    9.543049    9.722165    6.024503
> ```
>
> L5  9.29892055  3.492024    5.233948    16.87845    9.167887    9.77717 2.20739 18.79595    4.739065    8.99207 5.028492    18.48585
> L6  8.23894162  19.88437    5.648878    13.01997    13.07837    19.7044 13.52688    9.590797    9.106094    8.525063    5.034002    18.3212     L7  15.9189548  8.445242    7.309853    16.72543    13.56793    11.75311    9.775173    18.93781    14.27615    8.761763    16.28925    5.344112

If you note the section under Heading 2 (made bold above), you will see a difference that I am unable to see why. Please guide!

Thanks to you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never clear your `row` accumulator. It starts empty, so when you add the contents from your first set of spreadsheet rows it works as expected. But then when you move to your second set, it still has the values from the first set in the list.

`zip` runs over the sequences in parallel and stops when one is exhausted, so the labels from your second iteration get paired with the values from your first - as you're seeing.

The simplest fix is to move your initializer `row = []` into the outer `for` loop:

```
for j,e in zip(row_index,row_end):
    row = []
    # etc
```